# Personal Best Practices for Information Security

Tags: audit

Am relatively new to security and am interested in learning ways in which I can best protect my own personal data and identity in general terms both on the internet and the applications I engage with (let's call this software) but also my own personal devices (hardware).

To begin, how can I best protect my own computer at home from infiltration?

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid your question is too broad for Security.SE. But feel free to ask more specific questions (after researching if they haven't been asked before).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably as many potential answers as there are ways to break into a computer.
Some tips:

1) Disconnect wifi when you're not using it. Attack surface is the amount of ways that a cracker can get in. Limit attack surface when you can. Internet is the path into your computer and should always be treated as such.

2) It is very easy for an attacker to search the internet for devices with known vulnerabilities. Punk crackers don't know anything besides a specific exploit and how to use a weapon that someone else made. Keep everything up to date to protect against these novice crackers. The talented ones aren't after your personal device. Really, just try not to be the easiest target.

3) Don't visit websites that you don't trust. All sorts of problems can happen from malicious websites. If the website redirects you somewhere that you didn't intend to go, that's fishy, don't go back there.

4) Don't download things from sources that you don't trust

5) Never give personal information on a site that you don't trust completely, and which doesn't start with https. Https is a more-secure version of http. Most self-respecting sites use https.

From [Wikipedia HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS):

> The main motivation for HTTPS is authentication of the visited website
>   and protection of the privacy and integrity of the exchanged data.

6) Some software asks to open holes in your firewall or to open a port. If anything asks for firewall modification, think about it and research it thoroughly. This is a step in attack-surface restriction.

7) This will be the most controversial piece, but it's the kind of thing you can't leave out. Windows is not secure and never will be, it's also the biggest target because it's the most widely used. This goes with 'don't be the easiest target. *Disclaimer, I have no affiliation with any Linux distribution, I am very biased against Windows however, and we're talking security here*. Open source distributions like Linux, (Ubuntu is a good one for beginners and is very user-friendly) will always be more secure. The source code is available, and more eyes on code tends to root out bugs/vulnerabilities. Bugs are found all the time in Linux, but that's a good thing, because they can be fixed, allowing less [Zero Day Vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)). Another option is Qubes, which is a brilliant design for software if you have time to look into it and experiment. (The main pitfall of Linux is the sheer code-size of it's kernel, big attack surface). If you do have Windows, use protection, it's a dirty world, antivirus I mean.

8) Delete all programs you obviously don't need. Limit attack surface. You're not using them anyway, and it would be a shame for a vulnerability in a program you don't need to be the gateway into your computer for malevolent crackers.

9) Pay heed to warnings that your computer gives you. If it asks for administrative privileges, that's an important decision. The brilliant people that write software at times try to protect ourselves from ourselves, and that's usually a good thing. Research what it's asking.

I'm sure I missed something, but it's a start. The more familiar you are with how people break into computers, the easier safety will be. So it would never hurt to just skim through [NVD Vulnerabilities Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search). But really. bad websites, bad downloads, old, non-updated software avoid them all like the plague.